# Problema obteniendo valores seleccionados de checbox en Jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, checkbox

recorro toda la tabla obteniendo los valores de los checkbox seleccionados el problema radica en que si me trae todos los valores menos el último seleccionado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso deberia imprimir los valores desde el 3 hasta el 11 pero no imprime este ultimo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el código que obtiene los valores del jtable

```
    String valor = "";
    int cantFilas = tableRamos.getRowCount();
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < cantFilas; i++) {

         if (tableRamos.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(true)) {

            valor = tableRamos.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();    //fila seleccionada, y valor guardado en la variable "valor"
            System.out.println(valor);
            //agregarRamos(valor, getaPersist());
         }

    }
```

Comment: quizas si pruebas con... `for(i = 0; i <= cantFilas; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que la estructura del `for` que tienes en tu código es la siguiente:
mientras que `i` sea menor que `cantFilas`

```
for(i = 0; i < cantFilas; i++) {

}
```

Entonces todo esta bien hasta que `i` es igual al número de la ultima fila, por eso no te imprime el ultimo, porque ya no es menor que `cantFilas` en ese momento es IGUAL a `cantFilas`, para que tome la ultima fila seria de las siguiente forma:

Mientras que `i` sea menor o igual que `cantFilas`

```
for(i = 0; i <= cantFilas; i++) {

    }
```

O en lugar de eso podrías sumarle 1 a `cantFilas` y el `for` tomaría la ultima fila.

Comment: Hola Alexander, gracias por tu respuesta pero mira que al agregar "<=" me arroja la siguiente excepción
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 42 >= 42
y la verdad no entiendo porque.

Comment: eso es porque sobrepasa la longitud de cantFilas